# Nats cannot create a queue subscription for a consumer without a deliver group

Tags: go, nats.io, nats-jetstream

I'm trying to create several subscribers in one queue so each message is read only by one of them. When I try to `QueueSubscribe` second time I get an error: `cannot create a queue subscription for a consumer without a deliver group`.

I've tried creating two subscribers in one app and tried running two instances as well, it's the same error.

Here're subscribers:

```
s1, err = js.QueueSubscribe(
        "KEYS.group",
        "queue",
        func(m *nats.Msg) {
            fmt.Printf("1: %s\n", m.Data)
        },
    )

s2, err = js.QueueSubscribe(
        "KEYS.group",
        "queue",
        func(m *nats.Msg) {
            fmt.Printf("2: %s\n", m.Data)
        },
    )
```

And publisher:

```
_, err := js.AddStream(&nats.StreamConfig{
        Name:     "KEYS",
        Subjects: []string{"KEYS.group"},
        Retention: nats.WorkQueuePolicy,  // tried with default policy if it may be relevant
    })

for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        msg := fmt.Sprintf(`{"key": "%d"}`, i)

        if _, err := js.Publish("KEYS.group", []byte(msg)); err != nil {
            print(err)
        }
    }
```

I've tried to add `Durable` attribute as well and it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occured because of the version of nats server (2.3.6), after update to 2.7.2 everything works fine. Library is not compatible with old versions.